# Argument types differ in normal and reflected operator overload (__sub__ / __rsub__)

Tags: python, numpy, operator-overloading

How do I get access to the properties of an numpy array after passing it through an righthand operator like `__rsub__`?

I wrote a very simple class in python that defines the two functions:

```
class test(object):
    def __sub__(self,  other):
        return other

    def __rsub__(self,  other):
        return other
```

Basically they should do the same. The left-hand operator `__sub__` works as expected, but it seems that the numpy array is stripped off its properties on the right-hand operator

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
lena = data.lena()

grayLena = rgb2gray(lena)
t = test()

## overloaded - operator
left_hand = t - grayLena
print left_hand
# Output: 
#array([[ 0.60802863,  0.60802863,  0.60779059, ...,  0.64137412,
#    0.57998235,  0.46985725],
#  [ 0.60802863,  0.60802863,  0.60779059, ...,  0.64137412,
#    0.57998235,  0.46985725],
#  [ 0.60802863,  0.60802863,  0.60779059, ...,  0.64137412,
#    0.57998235,  0.46985725],
#  ..., 
#  [ 0.13746353,  0.13746353,  0.16881412, ...,  0.37271804,
#    0.35559529,  0.34377725],
#  [ 0.14617059,  0.14617059,  0.18730588, ...,  0.36788784,
#    0.37292549,  0.38467529],
#  [ 0.14617059,  0.14617059,  0.18730588, ...,  0.36788784,
#    0.37292549,  0.38467529]])

right_hand = grayLena - t
print right_hand
# Output:
# array([[0.6080286274509803, 0.6080286274509803, 0.6077905882352941, ...,
#   0.6413741176470589, 0.5799823529411765, 0.4698572549019608],
#  [0.6080286274509803, 0.6080286274509803, 0.6077905882352941, ...,
#   0.6413741176470589, 0.5799823529411765, 0.4698572549019608],
#  [0.6080286274509803, 0.6080286274509803, 0.6077905882352941, ...,
#   0.6413741176470589, 0.5799823529411765, 0.4698572549019608],
#  ..., 
#  [0.1374635294117647, 0.1374635294117647, 0.1688141176470588, ...,
#   0.3727180392156863, 0.35559529411764706, 0.34377725490196076],
#  [0.1461705882352941, 0.1461705882352941, 0.18730588235294118, ...,
#   0.3678878431372549, 0.37292549019607846, 0.3846752941176471],
#  [0.1461705882352941, 0.1461705882352941, 0.18730588235294118, ...,
#   0.3678878431372549, 0.37292549019607846, 0.3846752941176471]], dtype=object)
```

So the difference between both operations is that `__rsub__` receives an array of dtype=object. If I would just set the dtype of this array, everything would work fine.

However, it works only with the return value, outside of `__rsub__`. Inside my `__rsub__` I get only rubbish, that I cannot convert back, namely if I do

```
npArray = np.array(other,  dtype=type(other))
```

I get a 1D array of the type (floats in my case). But for some reason, the shape information is lost. Has anyone done this or an idea how I can access the original properties of the array (shape and type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what the exact control flow inside the `ndarray`'s machinery is, but what's happening in your case is more or less clear:

What `ndarray` is delegating to your object's `__rsub__` method is not the overall substraction operation, but the substraction of your object from each of the items in the array. And apparently when it has to delegate an operation to the object's methods, the return type is set to `object` regardless of what gets returned. You can check it with this slight modification of your code:

```
class test(object):
    def __sub__(self,  other):
        return other

    def __rsub__(self,  other):
        return other if other != 1 else 666

In [11]: t = test()

In [12]: t - np.arange(4)
Out[12]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [13]: np.arange(4) - t
Out[13]: array([0, 666, 2, 3], dtype=object)
```

I don't think there is an easy way of overriding this behaviour. You could try [making `test` a subclass of `ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-wrap-for-ufuncs) with a high `__array_priority__` and abuse a little the `__array_wrap__` method:

```
class test(np.ndarray):
    __array_priority__ = 100

    def __new__(cls):
        obj = np.int32([1]).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __array_wrap__(self, arr, context) :
        if context is not None :
            ufunc = context[0]
            args = context[1]
            if ufunc == np.subtract :
                if self is args[0] :
                    return args[1]
                elif self is args[1] :
                    return args[0]
        return arr
```

And now:

```
>>> t = test()
>>> np.arange(4) - t
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> t - np.arange(4)
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

But:

```
>>> np.arange(4) + t
test([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> t + np.arange(4)
test([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

It is a little bit wasteful, because we are doing the operation of adding the `1` inside `t` to every value in the array, and then silently discarding it, but I can't think of any way of overriding that.

Comment: Wow great, I will try that out. I need it only for backward compatibly reasons, so it does not have to be efficient, it just has to give the right result.

Comment: @user2156909 A couple more pointers: I have made `test` a single element array so that it can broadcast against any shape, tried it first with a 0-D array and it failed. You may also want to consider what value to give the array, I chose `1` to show that only when the `ufunc` is `subtract` are we discarding the result of the operation. If your object may show up in other operations, you may want to check for more `ufuncs`, or give it another value.

Comment: In my case subclassing ndarray was anyway the better way to go, because I just wanted to subtract a data-array in my test class. If one wants to call a more fancy function, `__array_wrap__` worked fine too. Thx